# VB.NET Array/Hashtable Issue

Tags: vb.net, arrays, hashtable

I am trying to make an array of hashtables. I don't know if this is the best solution, in PHP I would just do a multi-dim array, but it's not so easy in .NET. I am pretty new o VB, so if there is a better solution for this please explain.

I have 2 emails fields for a contact, and a contact can have many. I just want to load in the first two on the edit page for editing, whatever they may be.

```
Private Sub loadPrimaryContactEmails(ByVal db As CRMDataDataContext, ByVal contactID As Guid)
        Dim q = (From ce In db.ContactEmails Where ce.ContactID = contactID Select ce).Take(2)
        Dim Emails As Array
        Dim count = 0
        For Each email In q
            Emails(count) = New Hashtable
            Emails(count).Add("email", email.Email)
            Emails(count).Add("label", email.Label)
            Emails(count).Add("id", email.ContactEmailID)
            count = count + 1
        Next
        txtPCEmail1.Text = Emails(0).Item("email")
        txtPCEmail1Label.Text = Emails(0).Item("label")
        lblEmail1ID.Text = Emails(0).Item("id")

        txtPCEmail2.Text = Emails(1).Item("email")
        txtPCEmail2Label.Text = Emails(1).Item("label")
        lblEmail2ID.Text = Emails(1).Item("id")
    End Sub
```

I get the error the first time I try to reference my array:

```
txtPCEmail1.Text = Emails(0).Item("email")
```

The error is:

```
Object variable or With block variable not set.
```

It builds, so I thought it might work. I can't just loop through my datasource because I have to explicitly set textbox fields. Is there a better way to go about doing this? Or is there a way to make an array of hashtables work?

EDIT - here is the good code:
So I went w/ the HybridDictionary...

```
Private Sub loadPrimaryContactEmails(ByVal db As CRMDataDataContext, ByVal contactID As Guid)
        Dim q = (From ce In db.ContactEmails Where ce.ContactID = contactID Select ce).Take(2)
        Dim Emails As New HybridDictionary()
        Dim count = 1
        For Each email In q
            Emails.Add("email" + NCStr(count), email.Email)
            Emails.Add("label" + NCStr(count), email.Label)
            Emails.Add("id" + NCStr(count), email.ContactEmailID)
            count = count + 1
        Next
        txtPCEmail1.Text = Emails("email1")
        txtPCEmail1Label.Text = Emails("label1")
        lblEmail1ID.Text = Emails("id1")

        txtPCEmail2.Text = Emails("email2")
        txtPCEmail2Label.Text = Emails("label2")
        lblEmail2ID.Text = Emails("id2")
    End Sub
```

SO yeah, kind of a hack, but I don't feel like I should have to making special methods just to load some data into a dictionary or array or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Phil is right you haven't specified the Initial Size of the Array.

And as suggested by him Use generic list or I would recommend

"System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" Class or "System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary" class

Comment: I like the hybridDictionary...I'll post code in an edit on the post

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in VB.NET are different than in PHP.  You will need to define the size of your array *before* attempting to set elements of the array.

Better yet, consider using the generic `List<T>` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Build the hashtable first and then build the array.

```
    Dim hash As New Hashtable()
    hash.Add("Header", shortModel)
    hash.Add("SpecInfo", specinfo)
    hash.Add("SerialNumber", serie & "-L")
    hash.Add("SerialNumber2", serie)
    hash.Add("seriel", serie & "-L")
    hash.Add("serie", serie)
    hash.Add("Product", modelBase)
    hash.Add("varBC", bc)
    hash.Add("box_id", boxId.Substring(4).ToString)

    Dim dt As DataTable = DbUtil.GetCursor("SFISM4.PKG_AGENCY.sp_get_print_param", {New OracleParameter("in_serie", "3CE5151ZW4")})
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        hash.Add(row("NAME"), row("VALUE"))
    Next


    Dim mArray(hash.Count() - 1, 1) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each row As DictionaryEntry In hash
        mArray(i, 0) = row.Key.ToString()
        mArray(i, 1) = row.Value.ToString()
        i = i + 1
    Next
```